# Free, preferably open source alternative to iMazing for Windows PC?

Tags: windows, ios

I want a free, preferably open source, iphone file manager that I can install on Windows. Main requirement is to easily sync all photos and copy them to PC. In the past I've used iFunBox and it was easy and worked fine, it even renamed the photos with a standard date prefix but it seems to be discontinued and newer versions don't work with my iphone 13.

Requirements:

- Easily sync/copy all my photos to PC connected via USB
- Copy all files from a whatsapp chat Other backup tools?
- Free